# Switch back from view to tab bar view

Tags: xcode4

I am trying to learn how to work with Xcode 4.5.

I have created a tab bar and would like to switch from one of the tab bar views (profile) to another view (settings -not within the tab bar menu), and back. I use below code to go to the:

```
- (IBAction)goToProfile:(id)sender {

    ProfileViewController * profile = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:profile animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It works fine to go to settings, but when I go back from settings view to Profile, the tab bar menu is gone. How can i go back to profile view and see the tab bar again?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can either fix it with some code or you can just make some changes in your storyboard.
If you Put a Navigation Controller between your Tab Bar Controller and the View of your selected Tab (Profile in your case). If you use a push segue to go to the next View it will take the Tabbar to the next view and also a "Back" Button. (Settings in your case)

Here's an example of my App my jubla3ForthViewController would be your ProfileViewController and one of my jubla3PDFOnlineViewControllers would be your SettingsViewController.

http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=bildschirmfoto2013-01x2kti.png
(im not allowed to post direct images because of my low reputation points)

I hope this was usefull. If it was don't forget to push the up Arrow.